# Inline listing shortcut

Tags: lstlisting

I have defined the following abbreviation for inline listings:

```
\newcommand{\lsin}[2]{\lstinline[columns=fixed]{#1}}
```

but when I use this as "`\lsin{SELECT}` clause...", it eats up the space after it as well as the first character of the next word so the result comes out as

SELECTlause

Anyway I can fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified `\lsin` to take two arguments but only use one, which is why the `c` of `clause` is gobbled.

More importantly though, this definition will cause problems because `\lstinline` does catcodes changes which you prevent from taking effect by scanning its argument before the changes. You can prevent this by saying

```
\newcommand*\lsin{\lstinline[columns=fixed]}
```

Comment: Yes, I discovered that as well and posted something but it was probably concurrent with yours and the admin deleted my comment. In any case, many thanks and I appreciate the other correction; I will fix it.